# why the split line of tmux within putty shows different（xxxxx， qqqqqq）in these tow cases？

Tags: tmux

Why the split line of tmux within PuTTY shows different（xxxxx， qqqqqq）in these tow cases？
If I do not set PuTTY any thing（the default "Use font encoding"）, the split line of pane shows like following:
[image]

But it can't show Chinese word correctly, so I set PuTTY's Window -> Translation -> Remote character set to UTF-8. Then the split line of pane become to like that:
[image]

Using “xxx qqqq” seems very ugly.

BTW: echo $LANG shows “zh_CN.UTF-8”

So, in this case, How to show Chinese word correctly with the first split line?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Putty with character set set to UTF-8.

Launching tmux with -u option did the trick (`tmux -u`)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue except I was not trying to display Chinese characters. For the ugly line break ( xxxx qqqq), take a look at [Tmux borders displayed as x q instead of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483798/tmux-borders-displayed-as-x-q-instead-of-lines). For me, there are two version of tmux installed and switching to the newer version solves the problem. You may want to upgrade your tmux. Hope it helps.