# tmux in putty displays border as 'qqqqq' or 'xxxx'

Tags: freebsd, putty, tmux

This post is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199063/why-the-split-line-of-tmux-within-putty-shows-differentxxxxx-qqqqqqin-these-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483798/tmux-borders-displayed-as-x-q-instead-of-lines), however, without `putty`, the border could display properly. Therefore, I doubt this was caused by an old version of `tmux`.

I am running `FreeBSD 9.2-release` and `tmux 1.9a` (latest on `FreeBSD`).

I hope someone can give me solution as to why this happens and how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [`tmux` FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ):

> I use `PuTTY` and my `tmux` window pane separators are all `qqqqqqqqq's`!
>
> `PuTTY` is using a character set translation that doesn't support ACS line
>   drawing. With a Unicode font, try setting `PuTTY` to use a different translation
>   on the Window -> Translation configuration page. For example, change `UTF-8` to
>   `ISO-8859-1` or `CP437`. It may also be necessary to adjust the way `PuTTY` treats
>   line drawing characters in the lower part of the same configuration page.

That being said, I use `tmux 1.8` with `PuTTY 0.62`, "`UTF-8` translation", "Unicode line drawing code points" and a remote locale of `en_US.utf8` which works perfectly fine.

You probably have `PuTTY` configured to use Unicode without using a `UTF-8` locale on your FreeBSD box, or the other way round (if I switch my remote locale to `C` without touching my `PuTTY` settings I get the behaviour that you describe).

Comment: Had the same problem and this answer was the exact solution for it. I queried the remote host's locale with the command `locale` and saw it was `C`, so I changed Putty's "Remote character set" setting to `ISO-8859-15` and the tmux lines were beautiful as can be! Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with Putty when launching tmux on Linux 12.04 machine. Even setting the charset to UTF-8 in PuTTY (in the settings under Window > Translation > Remote character set) didn't solve the problem.

Launching tmux with -u option did the trick (`tmux -u`)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I could fix it by enabling a setting in PuTTY:

```
Window ->
   Translation ->
      Adjust how PuTTY handles line drawing characters ->
         [X] Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode
```

This makes sense, since the "lqqqk" sequences are what VT100 line drawing looks like if it is not interpreted as such.

Comment: I was having this issue natively, without tmux, and this fixed it for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The root reason was that the Linux system was using locale "POSIX".
The issue is resolved by:

```
# show system locale
locale

# using utf-8 as system locale
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# attach tmux
tmux a
```

Comment: That made a big difference with tmux, but I still have weirdness with 'lsblk' for example.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause may actually be related to Terminal character set switching: use `vttest(1)` to test character sets and see if your terminal support switching to DEC Special graphics and line drawing characters.

The escape sequence used by `gdb` and `ncdu`, etc, is `\033(0` to switch to "Character set 0 (DEC Special graphics and line drawing)"

You would want to configure your terminal emulator correctly. In the context of tmux, you are basically putting a terminal emulator inside another. So you would want to make sure they are both configured correctly.

The alternative, of course, is maybe to tell your application to use UTF-8 line drawing characters.

If you are using PuTTY, remember to check the box "enable VT-100 line drawing even in utf-8 mode" in `Window->Translation`.