# NCURSES border printing as q, x, when using UTF-8 and PuTTY

Tags: c++, putty, ncurses

I am trying to learn ncurses to add some functionality to my programs however I cannot seem to get my terminal settings to the point where the default ncurses window border shows up as expected.

Here is the output I am getting for a window with a box border:

```
  lqqqqqqqqk
  x        x
  x        x
  x        x
  mqqqqqqqqj
```

However I should be getting this:

```
  ┌────────┐
  │        │
  │        │
  │        │
  └────────┘
```

The only thing I am able to find that fixes this issue is setting my PuTTY Remove Character Set to be Latin-1 instead of UTF-8, however this messes up all of my other applications including VIM.

There were some related SO questions that I found ([**1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483798/tmux-borders-displayed-as-x-q-instead-of-lines) and [**2**](https://superuser.com/questions/818948/putty-and-curses-line-display-issue)) however neither of their solutions help me. The only interesting thing I pulled out of the second one is that if I run `printf '\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\220'` in my command line it prints out `└─┐` (which is correct...).

Here is the simple program I am using to test this:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ncurses.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstring>

 int main() {
     WINDOW *my_win;
     int startx, starty, width, height;
     int ch;

     initscr();
     cbreak();
     keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
     refresh();

     int height = 5;
     int width = 10;
     my_win = newwin(height, width, 1, 2);
     box(my_win, 0, 0);
     wrefresh(my_win);

     getch();

     endwin();
     return 0;
 }
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to check the documentation for whatever terminal program you're using, and pick the right `TERM` setting. That's it.

Comment: I am using PuTTY with ubuntu and my `TERM` is export `xterm-256color`. From what I understand that shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: And I also have `export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1` in my `.bashrc`

Comment: A brief Google search suggests that "putty-256color" is the correct `TERM` setting.

Comment: I remember running into that when I was doing my troubleshooting - it does not fix the issue

Comment: What happens if you unset `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`?

Comment: No change after I unset it :/

Comment: Do either `wborder()` with wide-character values, or `wborder_set()` with UTF-8 strings, work for you?  Are you compiling with and linking to an up-to-date ncurses lib that supports UTF-8?  Is your locale environment variable set?  Also, you’re not running something in 7-bit mode, are you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not initializing the locale.  Without that, ncurses will assume that it can use the terminal description.

Further reading:

- ncurses manual page, [*Initialization*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization):

> The  library uses the locale which the calling program has
>          initialized.  That is normally done with setlocale:
>
> `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`
>
> If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes that
>          characters  are  printable  as in ISO-8859-1, to work with
>          certain legacy programs.  You should initialize the locale
>          and  not  rely on specific details of the library when the
>          locale has not been setup.

- ncurses manual page, [*`NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS):

> During ***initialization***, the ncurses library checks for special cases where VT100 line-drawing (and the corresponding
>   alternate character set  capabilities)  described  in  the
>   terminfo are known to be missing.  Specifically, when running in a ***UTF-8 locale***, the Linux console emulator and the
>   GNU  screen program ignore these.  Ncurses checks the TERM
>   environment variable for these.  For other special  cases,
>   you  should  set  this  environment  variable.

Comment: Note that `LC_ALL` is defined in header `<locale.h>`

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be in putty configuration to make sure to check "Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode".

[Putty Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFKk8.png)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Whenever I have a fresh Putty instance, I search for this answer and make the required change. Many thanks!