# Pipe does not get printed in suckless terminal

Tags: terminal, x-st

I'm currently facing the problem that in `st` the pipe character `|` does not get printed in when using commands like `curl wttr.in/london` or in `tmux`.

`echo "|"` prints a pipe.

`tmux` etc. work fine in e.g. termite. I dont't even know where to look for a solution, do you have any idea?

[image: wttr on my end]

Answer (score 0):

wttr.in creator here.

I have just installed `stterm`, just to make sure that I have the same problem, and indeed, it does not display wttr.in output at all. It crashes, as it tries to display a unicode character (it was  ↘  in my case).

What you could do:

1. Check if curl rate.sx works for you (it has vertical bars too);
2. Try different options of wttr.in and check what of them do work and what does not (curl wttr.in/?0; curl wttr.in/?T etc.)
3. How exactly wttr.in frames look in your case? Is it something like `qxxxxx`?

If the answer for the last question is yes, it is a pretty trivial problem.
Please take a look at this question please: [Tmux borders displayed as x q instead of lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483798/tmux-borders-displayed-as-x-q-instead-of-lines)

In this case, the problem is that you have two options how you could draw frames:

1. (how rate.sx does) use special unicode characters;
2. q, x etc. and special terminal capabilities (how wttr.in does).

The solution could be to fix your termcap (as in the qeustion linked above).

Comment: Added a picture. rate.sx and other wttr options do not work either

Comment: @PatrickBateman then please read the linked answer (tmux borders displayed as x q)

Comment: That did not do it. However, a single os update fixed the error. I dont know which update in particular did the trick. Very strange.